# Inventory Restock with MATLAB (Low-Level I/O)

Tags: matlab, if-statement, file-io, while-loop, low-level-io

It's that time again where I/Os are confusing me. In this case, my goal is to write a function that takes in a .txt file of inventory items and another .txt file of price and outputs the total cost of restocking the items, as well as a .txt file that has the original inventory data and the amount of items needed to be restocked. For example:

```
Inventory Data:

Buns #50 #63
Burgers #32 #55
Ketchup #6 #10
Hotdogs #4 #35
Mustard #7 #8
```

Note: The header is included in the .txt file and there will always be five items to restock

My output file should read as:

```
Inventory Data:

Buns #50 #63
Burgers #32 #55
Ketchup #6 #10
Hotdogs #4 #35
Mustard #7 #8


Restocking Data:

Buns #63 #13
Burgers #55 #23
Ketchup #10 #4
Hotdogs #35 #31
Mustard #8 #1
```

and my output total should be 271 because

```
Prices:

Buns $2
Burgers $5
Ketchup $1
Hotdogs $4
Mustard $2
```

Amro was kind enough to help me figure out how to pull out the lines I need, and how to subtract my Needed from what I have. Now my last struggle (and the last hurdle I need to overcome before I can better personalize the problem), is figuring out how to write a final that outputs the original data, as well as the restocking data. It has to look like the test case

```
 function[restock_cost] = inventory2(file, prices)

%// Reads both files
fh = fopen(file, 'rt');
C = textscan(fh, '%s', 'Delimiter','');
inventory = C{1};
fclose(fh);
Original = C{:};
Original = char(Original);

fh2 = fopen(prices, 'rt');
D = textscan(fh2, '%s', 'Delimiter','');
prices = D{1};
fclose(fh2);

%// Breaks up inventory data
inventory(1) = [];
x = regexp(inventory, '(\w+) #(\d+) #(\d+)', 'tokens', 'once');
x = vertcat(x{:});
itemName = x(:,1);
itemHave = str2double(x(:,2));
itemNeeded = str2double(x(:,3));
itemName = char(itemName);


%// Determines what needs to be restocked and how much is needed
Restock = itemNeeded - itemHave;

%// Breaks up price info
prices(1) = [];
x = regexp(prices, '(\w+) \$(\d+)', 'tokens', 'once');
x = vertcat(x{:});
item = x(:,1);
prices = str2double(x(:,2));

%// Finds the price
restock_cost = sum((Restock .* prices));

%// gets the business name
[name, ~] = strtok(file,'_');

%// Finds the size of Original(may help)
[r,c] = size(Original);
[r2,c2] = size(itemName);
[r3,c3] = size(itemNeeded);

%// Starts to write my output file.
fh2 = fopen([name '_RestockingData.txt'], 'wt');
fprintf(fh2, 'Inventory Data: \n');
fprintf(fh2, '\n');

for i = 2:r %// Don't want the header included
    fprintf(fh2, Original(i,1:c));
    fprintf(fh2,'\n');
end
fprintf(fh2, '\n');
fprintf(fh2,'\n');
fprintf(fh2, 'Restocking Data: \n');
fprintf(fh2,'\n');

for j = 1:r2
    fprintf(fh2, itemName(j,1:c2));
    fprintf(fh2,' #%d ', itemNeeded(j));
    fprintf(fh2, '#%d', Restock(j));
    fprintf(fh2,'\n');
end

end
```

This is close, but I need it to output the restocking data with only a single space inbetween the item name and the numbers. Instead it's giving me:

```
Inventory Data: 

Chips #40 #100    
Lettuce #80 #90   
Cheese #22 #60    
Tortillas #65 #100
Tomatoes #40 #70  



Restocking Data: 

Chips     #100 #60
Lettuce   #90 #10
Cheese    #60 #38
Tortillas #100 #35
Tomatoes  #70 #30
```

I've also tried this:

```
Restock_Data = {};
Restock_Data = [Restock_Data, {itemName, itemNeeded, Restock}];
Restocking = {Restock_Data};
Kill_Cell = [{Restocking}];

for j = 1:r2

    fprintf(fh2, Restock_Data(j));
    fprintf(fh2,'\n');
end
```

I need to convert my cell into some other form, but indexing it (As you can see in Kill_Cell) isn't working. 
    end

That should be everything. Here are notes given to me just in case:

```
Notes: 
   - All inventory numbers will have a # in front of them 
   - All the prices will have a $ in front of them and will always be a
     full dollar amount.
   - When creating the new output every item should be seperated by a space
       Ex. 'Chips #5 #2'
   - There will always be 5 items to stock.
   - If your output file is not EXACTLY the same as the solution txt file,
     then you will receive 0 credit for it.
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the `textscan` function? That is probably the one best suited to your needs. Or are you supposed to use lower level functions?

Comment: I tried to use textscan, but I couldn't quite figure out how to use it properly. We weren't necessarily taught textscan, but it's in the book. It's just not very well explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to use textscan to read the inventory file:

```
fid = fopen('inventory.txt', 'rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s #%d #%d', 'HeaderLines',1, 'CollectOutput',true);
fclose(fid);
```

The data parsed:

```
>> C
C = 
    {5x1 cell}    [5x2 int32]

>> C{1}
ans = 
    'Buns'
    'Burgers'
    'Ketchup'
    'Hotdogs'
    'Mustard'

>> C{2}
ans =
          50          63
          32          55
           6          10
           4          35
           7           8
```

---

You could also read the file simply as a cell-array of string lines (I've used this in my previous answers to your questions):

```
fid = fopen('inventory.txt', 'rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter','');
C = C{1};
fclose(fid);
```

The result in this case:

```
>> C
C = 
    'Inventory Data:'
    'Buns #50 #63'
    'Burgers #32 #55'
    'Ketchup #6 #10'
    'Hotdogs #4 #35'
    'Mustard #7 #8'
```

---

## EDIT:

Like I've showed, first we read the files as a cell array of strings (lines of text):

```
% read both files
fid = fopen('inventory.txt', 'rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter','');
inventory = C{1};
fclose(fid);

fid = fopen('prices.txt', 'rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter','');
prices = C{1};
fclose(fid);
```

Next we use regular expressions to match patterns in the text:

```
% parse inventory data
inventory(1) = [];
x = regexp(inventory, '(\w+) #(\d+) #(\d+)', 'tokens', 'once');
x = vertcat(x{:});
itemName = x(:,1)
itemHave = str2double(x(:,2))
itemNeeded = str2double(x(:,3))

% parse prices data
prices(1) = [];
x = regexp(prices, '(\w+) \$(\d+)', 'tokens', 'once');
x = vertcat(x{:});
item = x(:,1)
price = str2double(x(:,2))
```

Finally you can apply your logic to restock inventory, and print the required output...

Comment: This is the exact code I was about to write. You saved me the trouble.

Comment: So the %s in the cell-array make-up is where the file info is inputted correct? Not by me, but by MATLAB. Then I guess 'Delimiter' makes it the default delimiter, so I'd say '/n'? And then I'm not too sure what the '' bit is for. Populating an empty string or what?

Comment: @JessicaMarie: `textscan` is used to read rows of data. The second argument is the "format specifier" which tells `textscan` how many fields to read from each row and of what type. By specifying `'%s'`, I'm saying I want to read a single field of string. The last option (`delimiter=''`) is necessary here because by default the fields are white-space delimited, and by specifying an empty string (`''`) as delimiter, the field will effectively go on until the end of the line. Hence we get one whole string line per row.

Comment: `textscan` is a powerful function with many options accepted. I refer you to the docs for all the details.. Its documentation is several pages long, which tells how complicated it is :)

Comment: @Amro Hence why I probably haven't learned it yet, but I can figure out the jist of it, I should be good. Now I just have one more question: How do I subtract my values? I up-dated my code using yours and all I need to do is subtract what I need, from what I have. Cellfun isn't working.

Comment: Similar to my [previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351797/altering-text-in-a-txt-file-and-creating-a-new-file-output-in-matlab#comment41386239_26354771), regular expressions come to mind. I'll post some code to illustrate.. btw you should pay attention that the first cell as it contain the header line, so you want to make sure you exclude that from your text extraction process..

Comment: I feel like you just don't like strtok lol I have a new desire to learn regex

Comment: @JessicaMarie: one should always use the best tool for the job, and for this kind of text processing, regular expressions are really flexible and powerful... I'm surprised you haven't been introduced to regex as part of your uni course, seeing that most of the homework problems you posted are of this nature.

Comment: I just think Low-Level I/Os are my weakness, but no. Regex was not taught. We have't even learned strsplit, but I use that. They seem pretty similar in what they do, only strsplit is a bit easier to understand.